# Split a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, split, concurrenthashmap

I have a ConcurrentHashMap. I need to make parallel operations over it. How can i split in 2/3/4... parts?

This is my example with a simple array

```
public class Summation extends Thread {

private int[] arr;

private int low, high, partial;

public Summation(int[] arr, int low, int high)
{
    this.arr = arr;
    this.low = low;
    this.high = Math.min(high, arr.length);
}

public int getPartialSum()
{
    return partial;
}

public void run()
{
    partial = sum(arr, low, high);
}

public static int sum(int[] arr)
{
    return sum(arr, 0, arr.length);
}

public static int sum(int[] arr, int low, int high)
{
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }

    return total;
}

public static int parallelSum(int[] arr)
{
    return parallelSum(arr, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
}

public static int parallelSum(int[] arr, int threads)
{
    int size = (int) Math.ceil(arr.length * 1.0 / threads);

    Summation[] sums = new Summation[threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        sums[i] = new Summation(arr, i * size, (i + 1) * size);
        sums[i].start();
    }

    try {
        for (Summation sum : sums) {
            sum.join();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

    int total = 0;

    for (Summation sum : sums) {
        total += sum.getPartialSum();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Now i want to do the same but with a ConcurrentHashMap. Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @KennerDe Its not possible. If you need to read a map/list and make something with the objects, u can do this:

1) Copy ConcurrentHashMap to other map/list.
2) Get iterator of the copy.
3) Add to a Executors.newFixedThreadPool (for example) a new task with the object.